# Parse JSON request with REGEX

Tags: json, regex

I'd like to parse the JSON output from an IEX Cloud stock quote query: https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/quote?token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

I have tired to use Regex101 to solve the issue:
https://regex101.com/r/y8i01T/1/

Here is the Regex expression that I tried:`"([^"]+)":"?([^",\s]+)`

Here is the example of a IEX Cloud stock quote output for Apple:

```
{
     "symbol":"AAPL", 
     "companyName":"Apple, Inc.", 
     "calculationPrice":"close", 
     "open":204.86, 
     "openTime":1556285400914, 
     "close":204.3, 
     "closeTime":1556308800303, 
     "high":205, 
     "low":202.12, 
     "latestPrice":204.3, 
     "latestSource":"Close", 
     "latestTime":"April 26, 2019", 
     "latestUpdate":1556308800303, 
     "latestVolume":18604306, 
     "iexRealtimePrice":204.34, 
     "iexRealtimeSize":48, 
     "iexLastUpdated":1556308799763, 
     "delayedPrice":204.3, 
     "delayedPriceTime":1556308800303, 
     "extendedPrice":204.46, 
     "extendedChange":0.16, 
     "extendedChangePercent":0.00078, 
     "extendedPriceTime":1556310657637, 
     "previousClose":205.28, 
     "change":-0.98, 
     "changePercent":-0.00477, 
     "iexMarketPercent":0.030716437366704246, 
     "iexVolume":571458, 
     "avgTotalVolume":27717780, 
     "iexBidPrice":0, 
     "iexBidSize":0, 
     "iexAskPrice":0, 
     "iexAskSize":0, 
     "marketCap":963331704000, 
     "peRatio":16.65, 
     "week52High":233.47, 
     "week52Low":142, 
     "ytdChange":0.29512900000000003 
}
```

I want to save the key value pairs in the JSON response without quotes around the key and gather the value starting after the colon (:). I need to exclude any quotes for text, the comma at the end of each line and include the last key-value pair that does not include a comma at the end of the line.

For example, `"peRatio":16.65,` should have the key equal to `peRatio` and the value equal to `16.65`. Or another example, `"changePercent":-0.00477,` should have a key equal to `changePercent` and a value of `-0.00477`. If it's a text such as `"companyName":"Apple, Inc.",`, it should have a key equal to  `companyName` and a value equal to `Apple, Inc.`

Also, the last JSON key-value entry: `"ytdChange":0.29512900000000003` does not have a comma and that needs to be accounted for.

Comment: DON'T PARSE JSON with regex, use a real parser.

Answer (score -1):

You most likely do not need to parse your data using regex. However, if you wish/have to do so, maybe for practicing regular expressions, you could do so by defining a few boundaries in your expression.

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/qmHMro/1) might help you to do that, which divides your input JSON values into three categories of string, numeric, and last no-comma values:

```
"([^"]+)":("(.+)"|(.+))(,{1}|\n\})
```

Then, you can use the <kbd>\n}</kbd> boundary for the last value, <kbd>""</kbd> boundary for your string values and no boundary for numeric values.

[image]

Comment: Emma, that's really helpful

Comment: I did adapt your method so I only captured 2 groups: key & value. So, I did the following update: ```"([^"]+)":(?:"(.+)"|(.+))(?:,{1}|\n\})```. This gave me 2 capture groups. Here is the Url: ```https://regex101.com/r/nOuWsx/1/```